# Trying to implement a basic class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and currently trying to create a very basic class representing a boat's length and weight... It seems I'm running into problems trying to split it into header and cpp files.

These are the simple files I'm working with...

Boat.h:

```
#ifndef BOAT_H_
#define BOAT_H_
class Boat{
public:
    Boat();
    Boat(int,int);

private:
    int length;
    int weight;
};

#endif /* BOAT_H_ */
```

Boat.cpp:

```
#include "Boat.h"

Boat::Boat(){
    length = 25;
    weight = 2500;
}

Boat::Boat(int newLength, int newWeight){
    length = newLength;
    weight = newWeight;
}
```

When compiling, I get errors in Boat.cpp about it being "first defined here". I've been following tutorials and trying to do like they do but I just can't seem to get this right. Here is the full error message. What am I missing?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/../Boat.cpp:4: multiple definition of `Boat::Boat()'
Main.o:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/..//Boat.cpp:4: first defined here
Boat.o: In function `Boat':
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/../Boat.cpp:4: multiple definition of `Boat::Boat()'
Main.o:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/..//Boat.cpp:4: first defined here
Boat.o: In function `Boat':
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/../Boat.cpp:9: multiple definition of `Boat::Boat(int, int)'
Main.o:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/..//Boat.cpp:9: first defined here
Boat.o: In function `Boat':
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/../Boat.cpp:9: multiple definition of `Boat::Boat(int, int)'
Main.o:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\Workspace\ClassTests\Debug/..//Boat.cpp:9: first defined here
```

Edit :
I was including Boat.cpp in the main instead of Boat.h... Problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: Please show the main program as well.

Comment: adding a trivial main to Boat.cpp - and it compiles for me on a recent gcc. Please show the complete example inclusive compiler call.

Comment: Are you by any chance including `Boat.cpp` rather than `Boat.h` from `Main.cpp`?

Comment: So I was including Boat.cpp instead of Boat.h. I wasn't aware it didn't work like that. Many thanks guys, newbie mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be sure what you did, but I did manage to generate your error with this main function:

```
#include "Boat.h"
#include "Boat.cpp"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Boat b; 

    return 0;
}
```

compiled in the following way:

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb main.cpp  Boat.cpp -o main
```

which results exactly in the error you reported. Whatever you did - you seem to have tried to include the `Boat.cpp` file twice, and by doing so, you have doubled the definition of your Boat class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you included your boat.cpp file in the module where there is function main. You need to include only header boat.h in the module with main.